# How to add gradient to font in MS Word using VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to add gradient to font in MS Word using VBA macro.
I am able to do it on the front end by going to:
Home > Font > Font Color > Gradient

I wish to do this using VBA macro.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Font.Fill` which will give you access to the `FillFormat` object.

Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.fillformat) on that to find the specific methods and properties you need.

Comment: thanks. I tried using font.fill.twoColorGradient and oneColorGradient. However, it does NOT behave as per the front end action. Rather those create only 2 gradient "stops", while the front end experience creates 3 gradient "stops".

Comment: Hi, I also tried adding gradientStops... getting the following error: Sub Macro3()

With Selection.Font.Fill

    .TwoColorGradient msoGradientFromCenter, 1

     
End With



Selection.Font.Fill.GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 192, 0), 0.5

End Sub   The error is Runtime error 445 object doesnt support this action

Comment: Please revise your question, including your code and indicate which line raises the error.